# Как можно автоматизировать добавление повторяющегося кода в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

я делаю кино сайт, и каждый раз при добавлении нового фильма я трачу много времени для копирования и изменения кода. Как можно упростить этот процесс?
Сам блок фильма

```html
<div class="movie-card" onclick="location.href='/films/1-garrypottervozvrashenie'">

  <div class="card-head">
    <img src="./assets/images/movies/гарри потер.webp" alt="Гарри Поттер Возвращение в Хогвартс" class="card-img">

    <div class="card-overlay">
      <div class="rating">
        <ion-icon name="star-outline"></ion-icon>
        <span>8.5 FHD</span>
      </div>

      <div class="play">
        <ion-icon name="play-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">Гарри Поттер Возвращение в Хогвартс</h3>

    <div class="card-info">
      <span class="genre">Документальный</span>
      <span class="year">2022</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Используйте циклы вашего ЯП

Comment: Вы всю информацию о фильме прямо в html храните?